# Unable to return a value from jQuery.ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to use jQuery Validator to check against the server when a user is signing up for if their desired username is already taken. The PHP script `untaken.php` does this job, returning `ok` if the username is available, or `taken` if it is taken.

My entire source is below, however the line in question is this:

```
return data != "taken";
```

Currently the message "Username already taken" permanently appears. However if I change it to:

```
console.log( data != "taken" );
```

and type in the text box I see in the console `true` and `false` messages exactly when I expect them. That's how I know the design itself isn't to blame, it's just the fact that I can't return anything from the `success` clause in jQuery.ajax.

```
$.validator.addMethod("userCannotBeTaken", function(value, element){

        var check;

        check = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "untaken.php",
            data: ({ "user" : value }),
            dataType: "text",

            success: function(data){
                return data != "taken"; //return false if taken or true if not, based on response
            }
        });


    }, "Username already taken");
```

How can I return something from within `jQuery.ajax`?

Comment: is it correct : **data: ({ "user" : value })** i think this should be like this: data: { "user" : value },

Comment: @Jai both work from what I can see. Will use yours, it's probably more correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was overthinking the whole thing and it can be easily done with jQuery Validator's built-in `remote` method. Here's my code if it helps someone:

Rule in validator script:

```
remote: "untaken.php"
```

PHP:

```
<?php

//mysql info
[snip]

//connect to database
$sql = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);

//Populate variable
$newun = $sql->real_escape_string( $_GET['newuser'] );


//Do the actual checks

$un_already_taken = $sql->query("
    SELECT username FROM logins WHERE username = '$newun'
"); //check if UN already in DB

if($un_already_taken->num_rows > 0) //un taken already
    print "false"; //tell jQuery to not submit form
else
    print "true"; //tell jQuery all is good
```

As easy as printing "true" or "false". Note it uses GET (ie. URL paramaters) not POST, and the GET variable is the `name` of the field it is validating (in my case `newuser`)

Answer (score 0):

To return data to the `ajax` function, you need to print or echo the result in your `untaken.php` page.

soemething like:

```
echo $result;exit;
```

Then Try to alert the data inside `success` function 
and debug the result with

```
alert(data);return false;
```

Comment: I've done that, just with `console.log` instead of `alert`. Gives the right result with that.

Answer (score 0):

The function you define for the success action is a callback.

When you make an ajax call, it is done asynchronously, (meaning the script continues executing while the browser connects to the server.  You can't use return when dealing with callbacks because they are executed later, rather than immediately as a typical function.

This might make more sense: http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/

The success function should perform whatever actions that you want to happen after you get the data back to the server ie: alert the user that the username is taken.

Comment: I need to return a boolean, due to the nature of jQuery Validator's extensions. Is there a way to perform something on success (ie. return true or false), but as a normal function, not a callback?

Comment: I tried `async: false` (from jQuery docs), but still no luck. Plus this also locks up the browser so you can't see what you're typing for a second or so, very annoying

Comment: It makes sense that it would lock it up.  It's probably making a request to the server for every character entered.

I'd advise not using the validator for this and building something custom.